# how can i hide and show a div with a toogle-slide if i have more then one toggle-slide

Tags: hide, show, state

i will to hide and show a div with my toggle-slide (on the ride site it is the on off slider). I have more than one toggle-slide. For my Example i use the eq() even and i will to solve this with **state** not with toggle().

Here my start Code:

```
jQuery('.menu_filter').find('.toggle-slide').eq(0).click(function(){
    jQuery('.dark_red_gradient').hide("slow");
});
```

Here my Testsite:

http://devauth.labscope.de/htmlapp/report-overview.html

First Click to hide the div and second Click to show the div again.

I hope someone have idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simply concatenate some classes or id´s to get multiple handles..

e.g.

```
jQuery('.menu_filter#filter1').find('.toggle-slide#slide1').eq(0).click(function(){
    jQuery('.dark_red_gradient').hide("slow");
});
jQuery('.menu_filter#filter2').find('.toggle-slide#slide2').eq(0).click(function(){
    jQuery('.dark_red_gradient').hide("slow");
});
jQuery('.menu_filter#filter3').find('.toggle-slide#slide3').eq(0).click(function(){
    jQuery('.dark_red_gradient').hide("slow");
});
```

or less..

furthermore you can do the same with classes..

e.g.

```
jQuery('.menu_filter.filter1').find('.toggle-slide.slide1').eq(0).click(function(){
    jQuery('.dark_red_gradient').hide("slow");
});
jQuery('.menu_filter.filter2').find('.toggle-slide.slide2').eq(0).click(function(){
    jQuery('.dark_red_gradient').hide("slow");
});
```

or merge classes and id´s..

to toggle any div´s hide|show state use something like this

```
jQuery('.menu_filter#filter1').find('.toggle-slide#slide1').eq(0).click(function(){
    jQuery('.dark_red_gradient').toggle(".invisible");
});
```

css part for this

```
.dark_red_gradient {
    display: block; // or whatever
    [...] // your other definitions
}

.invisible {
    display: none;
}
```

as you say you want NOT solve it with trigger but with state:

you mean [this](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.state/) ?

Comment: so state will only give you the actual state as a string.. you want to hide/show the div if you call state or if you call .resolve/.reject?